# Using AudioPlayer node changes sampling frequency to 44,100

Tags: audiokit

I have the following audio engine chain in Audiokit :

48kHz audio file -> AudioPlayer -> some node -> NodeRecorder -> audio file

Even though the input file is 48kHz , the recorded file comes out at 44,100 Hz.

How to force AudioKit to stay at 48KHz throughout ?

I'm using Audiokit 5.3

Btw, If I use microphone as input instead of file, then all is well, the recorded file comes out at 48kHz.
Mic input -> some node -> NodeRecorder -> audio file

So I suspect the AudioPlayer node is doing some unrequested resampling, how to turn that off?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you can change the value of defaultAudioFormat in the Settings.swift in the AudioKit package. That looks like the only place the sample rate is being set explicitly: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/search?q=44

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Nick , this put me in the right direction.
Actually all that was needed to run the engine at 48kHz was to add this line at init():

```
Settings.audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 48000, channels: 2) ?? AVAudioFormat()
```